# Set border color on summernote focus state

Tags: jquery, css, html, summernote

I would like to set the border color of the summernote div to a light blue color on focus and set it back to neutral on focusout.

I managed to remove the shadow around the div by using the following:

```
div.note-editor.panel.panel-default {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

The problem I have is I haven't found the way to style its state when focused. Using .focused or :focus did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

As per MDN docs, The `:focus` represents an element (such as a form input) that has received focus. On the other hand, The `:active`represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. In your case, it would be `:active` rather than `:focus`.

```css
div.note-editor.panel.panel-default {
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div.note-editor.panel.panel-default:active {
 outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="note-editor panel panel-default">
  Hello Focus
</div>
```

Comment: I actually want to add an outline/border on focus for the whole panel, however using :focus and outline did not do the trick for me either.

Comment: It's my first time setting this up, but this should work: https://jsfiddle.net/hfmhkc81/2/#&togetherjs=UUvfSpw7yM

Comment: You need to use :active instead of :focus. Please see my updated answer

Comment: It works! The colored border shows up, but it doesn't remain as I am typing in the html editor. Is there a way I could achieve that?

Comment: In this case you need to handle it by js

Comment: What are you even talking about, active means the style that is given is gonna be active during the click, active wont remain in there whike you type. focus on the other hand means the style well be active while the user is focused on the field and typing. and than there is hover which is gonna work when you hover over something.